# How to express the roots of a polynomial using its coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Vieta's formula's can be used to express the coefficients of a polynomial using its zeros, but can they also be used for the opposite, by solving a system of equations described by the formulas? For example, if one of the coefficients contains a parameter, then how can I show what influence it has on the roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Abel-Ruffini impossibility theorem, there is no formula for degree five and above.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem

---

If you want to know the influence of a single coefficient on the roots, say describe the relation between $x$ and the coefficient of the term of degree $k$ in

$$p(x)+\lambda x^k=0,$$

you can choose an arbitrary $x$ and deduce $\lambda(x)$. Then by differentiation,

$$p'(x)+\lambda'(x)x^k+k\lambda(x) x^{k-1}=0$$ gives you the sensitivity coefficient,

$$\frac{\lambda}{x}\frac{dx}{d\lambda}.$$

Comment: I believe the OP doesn't emphasize on a solution in radicals, but rather how varying a coefficient influences the roots.

Comment: My goal was showing that changing a coefficient doesn't influence the fact that a polynomial equation has only one real solution. I thought a formula relating them might come in handy.

Comment: @DaddyMike: if you don't ask the right question, don't expect the right answer. XY strikes again.

Comment: I only wanted to know about the formula though, the solution to the problem itself I wanted to find on my own. The theorem is relevant.

Comment: @DaddyMike Even when $\deg p(x) = 3$, for which a general explicit formula for the roots in terms of the coefficient is available, it's not so easy to read off that a particular root is real, so such formulas are not so useful for your purpose

Comment: @DaddyMike  In any case, the statement that you want to justify is not true. For example, $x^2 + \epsilon$ has exactly one real root for $\epsilon = 0$ but zero real roots for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: I know, the formulas only concerned specific polynomials.